# Recover data from a Nexus 4

Tags: data-recovery

The touch screen has stopped working. The side buttons still work.

No backups to any cloud services/pc and no sd card. No special apps installed.

Am I able to recover the data? I don't have any special equipment.

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: You can take backup of stuff in Internal SD card easily at this point (provided that you didn't check "Charge only" the last time you connected the device into PC). If the USB debugging is on, then you can backup App's data as well. And if you've root access, then you can backup lots of things. // Your phone boots well, right? -- Only touch screen is unresponsive, but the display and Android is fine.

Comment: @Firelord I am on the latest Android version I believe. I don't believe debugging was on and I am not sure about the "Charge only" option as I dont get any options when I plug it into the computer. Nothing happens when I plug it in. The device isn't rooted. Yes its just the touch screen that is unresponsive, it boots fine.